# C++ store same classes with different templates in array

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, containers

I have the following class:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    void method(const char *buffer);
    // the template T is used inside this method for a local variable
};
```

Now I need an array of instances of this class with different templates like:

```
std::vector<A*> array;
array.push_back(new A<uint32_t>);
array.push_back(new A<int32_t>);
```

But `std::vector<A*> array;` wont work, because I apparently need to specify a Template, but i can't so that because I store different types in this array. Is there some kind of generic type or an other solution?

Comment: Can you make just that one member function a template, instead of the whole class?

Comment: You could have all the `A`s inherit from a base, although that tends to be bad.

Comment: In addition to what Martinho said, `A` is not a type, it's a class template. So you can't use it as a template argument as in `std::vector<A>`.

Comment: How do you want to call `array[0].method(something);`, if you don't know what type the argument `something` needs to be?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes My goal was to select one of the classes in the array and call `method`. At this moment `method()` should already know which type to use.

Comment: @aschepler I changed the code slightly to shorten it. In reality i'm going to pass a `const char *` and the template type is used inside of the method to do a type conversion. I'm going to edit the question.

Comment: How could you possibly call `method` if you don't know what `T` is?! Your setup makes no sense.

Comment: Was going to type an answer, but @VaughnCato's is pretty much identical.  One more thing: you can probably make things easier on yourself if you can change from `vector<ABase*>` to `vector<unique_ptr<ABase> >` or `vector<shared_ptr<ABase> >` using either the new C++11 `std` smart pointers or Boost C++03 smart pointers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a base class:

```
class ABase {
public:
    virtual void method(const char *) = 0;
    virtual ~ABase() { }
};

template <typename T>
class A : public ABase
{
public:
    virtual void method(const char *);
};
```

then use it like

```
std::vector<ABase*> array;
array.push_back(new A<uint32_t>);
array.push_back(new A<int32_t>);
```

Comment: `ABase` should probably have private or deleted copy constructor and copy assignment.

Comment: @aschepler: I did miss the virtual destructor, but I'm not sure what would indicate that the instances should be non-copyable.